# How do I use the split function

Tags: vb.net, split, syntax-error

How do I use the split method in VB.NET? I tried:

```
arr.Split(New Char{','})
```

But it gives me an error. What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
arr.Split(New Char() { ","c })
```

`'` begins a comment.

Answer (score 0):

try this : 
    Dim ApplyTo As String = "Test1,Test2"
    asd = ApplyTo.Split(",")
    msgbox(asd(0)) 'Prints "Test1"
    msgbox.WriteLine(asd(1))